# Strange behaviour in pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was just curious as to what's going on here. I have 13 dataframes that look something like this:

df1:

```
time   val
00:00  1
00:01  2
00:02  5
00:03  8
```

df2:

```
time   val
00:04  5
00:05  12
00:06  4
```

df3:

```
time   val
00:07  8
00:08  24
00:09  3
```

and so on. As you can see each dataframe continues the time exactly where the other left off, which means ideally I would like them in one dataframe for simplicity sake. *Note the example ones I used are significantly smaller then my actual ones*. However, upon using the following:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i, usecols=[0,1,2]) for i in sample_files])
```

Where these 13 dataframes are produced through that list comprehension, I get a very strange result. It's as if I have set `axis=1` inside the `pd.concat()` function. If I try to reference a column, say `val`

```
df['val']
```

Pandas returns something that looks like this:

```
0    1
1    2
     ...
2    5
3    8
Name: val, Length: 4, dtype: float64
```

In this output it does not specify what happened to the other 11 `val` columns. If I then reference an index, as follows:

```
df['val'][0]
```

It returns:

```
0    1
0    5
0    8
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

which is the first index of each column. I am unsure as to why pandas is behaving like this, as I would imagine it just joins together columns with similar header names, but obviously this isn't the case.

If sometime could explain this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are not resetting the index after concatenation, but before selecting the data.

Try:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i, usecols=[0,1,2]) for i in sample_files])
df = df.reset_index(Drop=True)
df['val'][0]
```

Comment: Yep that works, I guess I just thought concat behaved differently then to how it actually does. Didn't know reset_index existed. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear! If the answer solves your question, consider hitting that upvote and green checkmark ;)

Comment: had to wait))))